# Please Onebox Wikiwand

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

[Wikiwand](http://www.wikiwand.com/) is a really nice plugin that beautifies wikipedia, but it does so by automatically converting [wikipedia URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow?oldformat=true) to [wikiwand URLs](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stack_Overflow).  These don't onebox.  It's possible to get the unaltered wikipedia URL from the wikiwand page, but it's a pain.

Everybody should use wikiwand anyway, so somebody make it onebox.

Comment: ... or just post the regular wikipedia url. Oneboxing doesn't have to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it appears there is no interest in oneboxing Wikiwand, I've developed a solution for those of us who use it. Install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), and run this script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive Google Chrome
Ctrl & c::
Send ^c
Sleep 10
ClipSaved = %clipboard%
StringLeft, URL, ClipSaved, 23
If URL = http://www.wikiwand.com
{
    StringTrimLeft, article, ClipSaved, 26
    clipboard = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki%article%
}
return
#IfWinActive
```

While this is running, any time you copy a Wikiwand link, it will convert it to a Wikipedia link. It won't affect you, as the Wikiwand plugin will automatically convert it back to a Wikiwand link when you attempt to visit it. It will, however, make it so "Wikiwand" links will onebox when you copy them into chat.

This version is for Google Chrome, to use it for other browsers you will have to replace "Google Chrome" in the script with the name of your browser as it appears in the title bar.

Answer (score 9):

> Wikiwand is a really nice plugin that beautifies wikipedia

Wikipedia is beautiful, and oneboxes too. Use the Wikipedia url instead of using Wikiwand.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply your own styles to Wikipedia, you can.

If you want to apply your own styles to Wikipedia oneboxes, you can, but it's your job (via a custom stylesheet, for example), not the SE devs.